# Error Running Commands against MongoDB Replica Set in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Running a small mongo replica set with a primary, a secondary and an arbiter. Below is an output of the rs.status() describing the set:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-09-22T11:01:11Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "mongo2:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 66657,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1411383252, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-09-22T10:54:12Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1411383118, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-09-22T10:51:58Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "warehouse:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 433,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-09-22T11:01:10Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-09-22T11:01:10Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "name" : "mongo1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 419,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1411383252, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-09-22T10:54:12Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-09-22T11:01:10Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-09-22T11:01:09Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "mongo2:27017"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

All servers are running mongo 2.6.4, the php MongoClient has been updated to the latest version. My computer is running osx 10.9. Running aggregation jobs in the mongo cli seems to be just fine, but as soon as I try to start an aggregation job, I get the following error:

```
CON FINE: Using 30000 from default with
```

I'm catching the exception and its code is 0. I can't really make sense of this exception, nor can I find any references to it online. The mongo logs seem to indicate that the connection is being opened and then closed, without any errors. Communication between the servers is also just fine, the keys are copied over and the hosts files are up to date.

I can't seem to be able to run even simple queries like

```
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://mongo2/?replicaSet=rs0');
$m->admin->command(array("ismaster" => 1))
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: That's actually the entire message? Do queries etc work in the mongo shell and the problem only happens when going through PHP?

Comment: yeah, that's the entire message, unfortunately. everything works just fine in the mongo cli

Comment: Is there a stack trace? I'm trying to track down where this could come from in the PHP driver code. 30000 looks like a timeout or a port number. Does it take about 30s for the exception to happen after a connection attempt? How are you connecting to the database? What function call/connection string (and how you connect with the shell might be good for comparison)?